# Alpine.JS access x-data function in JavaScript inside another fuction

Tags: javascript, jquery, alpine.js

I'm trying to move some inline alpine.js to an external JavaScript file, with the thought of being able to manipulate the state of for example a modal after a form submit with ajax.

So my modal with tailwind:

```
<div x-data="showFileModal" class="inline-block">
    <button type="button" @click="toggle">{{ __('Open Model') }}</button>

    <div x-show="openFileModal" class="flex fixed overflow-auto z-10 top-O right-0 bottom-0 left-0">
        <div x-show="openFileModal" class="w-2/5 p-5 mx-auto" @click.away="toggle">
            <form action="" method="">
                <button id="form-submit" type="submit">{{ __('Submit') }}</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My external JavaScript file:

```
window.showFileModal = () => {
    return {
        openFileModal: false,
        toggle() {
            this.openFileModal = ! this.openFileModal;
        }
    }
};

$('#form-submit').click(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    
   $.ajax({
       success: function (s)
       {
           showFileModal().toggle();
       }
   })
});
```

The toggle function on the button to open and close the model works, but trying to call it inside the ajax success function is not working. Even if i try it on a normal button without any ajax logic it also doesn't work. I either get no error in the console, or i get an error that toggle isn't a function if i try with a variation of using 'this'.

How can i call upon that toggle function outside of the showFileModal function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens most likely because your `showFileModal` module is not available where you're calling it. You're also mixing `Alpine.js` with `JQuery`, which shouldn't be necessary.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
<div x-data="showFileModal" class="inline-block">
<button type="button" @click="toggle">{{ __('Open Model') }}</button>

<div x-show="openFileModal" class="flex fixed overflow-auto z-10 top-O right-0 bottom-0 left-0">
    <div x-show="openFileModal" class="w-2/5 p-5 mx-auto" @click.away="toggle">
        <form action="" method="">
            <button type="submit" 
                    @click.prevent="submitForm()">
                {{ __('Submit') }}
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your JS you'd have to declare the function like

```
window.showFileModal = () => {
    return {
        openFileModal: false,
        toggle() { .. },
        submitForm(event) {
            // do your API request here
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That works, ty ! I didn't think of trying to put the function inside showFileModal, but makes the most sense in hind sight, as the entire scope revolves around showFileModal.